# Retain or copy UIKit elements

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, properties, uikit

**First Question**

When an object's property is retained in Objective-C, why does a second instance of the same class point to the same object? If you instantiate a new class, then you would logically want a separate class with separate properties. `retain` I understand increases the retain count only and `copy` will shallow copy.

I've created a class which has a retained `NSURLRequest`. I initialized two instances of that class. Changing the property on any of the created classes will change them for all. When I used copy on the property, it stopped doing that. Reading online however, it says that `copy` on an immutable object is essentially a shallow copy since you really do not want a separate entity since it can never be changed. In this case, `NSURLRequest` is immutable so how did my example work by invoking `copy` on an immutable object when it supposedly deep copied it? Here's how I copied it:

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        _request = [request copy];
    }

    return self;
}
```

**Second Question**

I've been reading that essentially for all immutable objects, I need to use `copy` and for mutable objects use `retain` (or now in ARC, `strong`). If IBOutlets are `weak` pointers, what if I draw my views without Interface Builder? Would `UIKit` elements be `copy` or `retain`/`strong`?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first question isn't clear and sounds like you're misunderstanding something. Can you post a snippet demonstrating what you're talking about? Your second question has an incorrect generalization -- usually you use `copy` for classes which have mutable subclasses (`NSString`, `NSArray`) and `retain`/`strong` for others. Further, `UIResponder` and its subclasses (which make up GUI elements) don't generally implement `NSCopying` and so can't be used in a `copy` property.

Comment: I rewrote my first question. I understood your answer to my second, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not really clear. You "called" _what_ "twice"? "changing a property on any of the created classes" -- you mean "created _instances_"? Did you set one instance's property to point to a new instance of `NSURLRequest`, or did you set all your instances to the _same_ `NSURLRequest` object and then change that? A [Small, Self-contained Example](http://sscce.org) would really help here.

Answer (score 0):

A retain tells iOS not to release that memory even if the original property or pointer sets itself to nil which would decrement the retain count. So if you do a shallow copy which would be assigning one pointer to an existing object it will retain it. If you need to do a deep copy then you should specify copy or create a copy constructor.

A weak reference is similar to using the old method of "assign" on a piece of memory that you do not want to increment the retain count on. There are situations where you can have circular references and could potentially never release the memory. If you do not use IB to create UIKit objects ARC will be sure to retain the memory for you assuming you have a valid pointer to that object. For instance if you have a UIButton pointer as a member of a view controller and you dynamically create a button it will retain that memory for as long as that pointer is valid and release it once the pointer is set to nil.

Comment: Oh alright. Please see my first question edit. As for the second question, thanks for the answer. So in general, if I retain a UIKit element and allocate it in init or viewDidLoad, it will stay for the lifetime of the view and once its unloaded, it will automatically decrement the count by 2 and deallocate it properly.

Comment: if you do an init on an object it will have a retain count of 1 and when you need to remove that object you will just call release on it to decrement the retain. That said if you use ARC you only have to worry about the life of the pointer and the compiler will do the work of inserting the correct retains and releases for you